# How would you get a switch statement in Java to print out on a GUI?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to make a magic 8 ball kind of program but, I don't know how to get the switch case statement to print out on a GUI. I'm not really sure what to do from here. I tried looking in my java books and the internet but, I can't find anything.
Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter a Yes or No question");
JTextField field = new JTextField(12);
JButton button = new JButton("Enter");

public Main() {
    super("MAGIC 8 BALL");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(label);
    add(field);
    add(button);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String question = field.getText();
    int ball;
    Random r = new Random();
    ball = r.nextInt(20);
    String answer = ball;
    switch (ball) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("It's certain");
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println("It's decidedly so");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Without a doubt");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Yes definitely");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("You may rely on it");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Probably");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Try again later");
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Better Not to Tell you");
        break;
    case 8:
        System.out.println("Cannot predict now");
        break;
    case 9:
        System.out.println("Cannot see reply right now");
        break;
    case 10:
        System.out.println("Concentrate and ask again");
        break;
    case 11:
        System.out.println("Don't count on it");
        break;
    case 12:
        System.out.println("My reply is no");
        break;
    case 13:
        System.out.println("Very doubtful");
        break;
    case 14:
        System.out.println("Outlook not so good");
        break;
    case 15:
        System.out.println("My sources say no");
        break;
    case 16:
        System.out.println("Yes");
        break;
    case 17:
        System.out.println("Signs point to yes");
        break;
    case 18:
        System.out.println("As I see it, yes");
        break;
    case 19:
        System.out.println("Yes definitely");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `switch(somevar) case 'whatever': call_output_to_gui_function_here();`

Comment: Design suggestion: Have your switch statement return the string (into a variable), then have **one** line that performs the output. Way more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

System.out outputs to the console/command line, not to the JFrame, you need to actually have a UI element to display your options.  A JLabel, or JTextArea, or something of the like

Answer (score 0):

You should create a JLabel instance variable and then update it with the corresponding switch statement and then add the JLabel to the panel of the JFrame.

```
JLabel message = new JLabel();

switch (ball) {
    case 0:
        message.setText("It's certain");
        break;
    case 1:
        message.setText("It's decidedly so");
        break;
    case 2:
        message.setText("Without a doubt");
        break;
    //do this till case n
```